# Must all discarded paper with God's name in Hebrew be buried in a genizah?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, disposal, genizah-storage

Discarded books and documents that contain the name of God *in Hebrew* must be buried in a genizah, and not burned or thrown in the trash.

But what if  the name of God in Hebrew is in a Christian or other non-Jewish document?  What if the document is secular or heretical or otherwise unholy to Jews?  What should we do with the document?

(A [previous answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14787/divrei-torah-written-by-a-heretic) suggested one should study the document before deciding what to do with it.  But one may not want to do this.  Would one be allowed to burn it based on the source alone?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14787/

Comment: It helps.  See my edit

Comment: How does your edit differentiate this question from that one?

Comment: The top answer seems to say that Leibowitz advises to study the document before deciding.  Is this halacha?

Comment: At least edit so that you’re asking on the answer; as it stands I don’t see how your question is different from that one.

Comment: Can anybody tell me at least what's actually being done?