Gentiles printing Jewish books vs. genizah
I have recently bought an English translation of the R' Hirsch Chumash, and it is written on its inner cover that the book was printed in China. Since there are always a few extra sheets coming of the printing press that are not bound eventually, I was wondering whether Jews should take care of them. On the one hand, gentiles are not obligated by the mitzvah of genizah, yet there is a concern that they may desecrate the Name of Hashem with such papers. What should a Jew ordering religious books from a gentile press do?

Please note that these two related questions are about non-Jewish or heretical books: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111129/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14787/15256

I don't understand this sentence: Since there are always a few extra sheets coming of the printing press that are not bound eventually, I was wondering whether Jews should take care of them. Can you clarify the question?

@shmosel There are always extra sheets for various reasons, if you visit a printing house, you'll see. The first copies are often not used, because sometimes you need to calibrate the printing machine for optimal quality. They also create a buffer for torn pages, stains on the paper, binding defects etc. So printing presses always print like 2-3% more, because it would be very costly to restart an industrial printing machine, and you simply cannot print 1-2 copies with an offset machine.

I think I've heard that printed texts have no kedusha until they're studied.

Many Jewish texts are indeed printed in China, they print 200m bibles a year and have real expertise in printing complex/heavy books. Not to mention the cost advantage
