# Tu Bishvat Seder Permissibility

Tags: halacha, provenance, tu-bishvat, shabbetai-tzvi

Given that [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13200/tu-bshvat-seder) answer notes that the particular ritual of the Tu Bishvat Seder is likely Sabbatean in origin (although the practice of eating fruit in general on Tu Bishvat dates from the 16th century) would there be any halakhic problem with participating in one?

Comment: eating fruit...dates from...:)