# Tu B'Shvat Seder: At night or day?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada, chagim-holidays, tu-bishvat

The Pri Etz Hadar, as incorporated in the [Chemdas Yamim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49705&st=&pgnum=285&hilite=), tells us of the idea of making a Tu B'Shvat Seder. It seems that most people (such as [here](https://www.shemayisrael.com/yomtov/tubshevat/TuBShevat.pdf), [here](http://www.aish.com/h/15sh/ho/48965616.html) and [here](http://ohr.edu/holidays/tu_bshvat/1460)) assume the Seder is meant to take place at night. I conjecture that they take the parallel to the Pesach Seder as an indication of the time of day. However, the Chemdas Yamim does not say clearly when the Seder is indeed meant to occur. In fact, in a number of places (such as [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49705&st=&pgnum=288) in the first paragraph) he uses the term בעצם היום הזה, which I would take to mean that the Seder should be had at noontime or at least during the day, as that phrase [usually](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%92) means.

Does anyone know of a clear source text that states when the Seder should take place?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13200.

Comment: The Sefer Mo'ed L'Kol Chai, in section 30:7 (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33683&st=&pgnum=521), says: **ליל** ט״ו בשבט ר״ה לאילנות ונהגו רוב תפוצות ישראל לסדר בשלחן מכל פירות.
Further, he writes in 30:8: "There are those who teach their young students all 15 Songs [of ascension, the Shir HaMaalos] in order that they'll be able to teach it at their father's table on the **night of** Tu B'Shvat"... So he definitely holds that whatever a person does for his Tu B'Shvat Seder, it should be at night. However, I don't know if this qualifies as an answer.

Comment: I once went to a friend's Tu Bishvat Seder-- and it was during the day.

Comment: I once made a Tu b'Shvat Seder-- and it was during the night.

Comment: LOL! Another case of inventing a new custom, and then others asking for _Halachot_ and other minutia about the invention.

Comment: A custom emerging from wise men is certainly nothing to scoff at. I merely how and when the custom was done. In the Kabbalistic framework, night and day have significantly different ambiences and I imagine they took that into account.

Comment: Except that the Chemdas Yamim is Sabbatean. The Gra believed so, many chassidic rabbeim banned it as Sabbatean, and academia is only split about whether it was actually written by Nathan of Gaza (the "prophet" who declared the reality of Shabbetai Zvi's messianic status) or a less famous follower.

Comment: It is Tu Bish'vat with a chirik.

Comment: R. David Sassoon (d. 1864) writes of the Jews in Baghdad in his מסע בבל, מהדורת מ. בניהו, ירושלים תשט"ו, עמ' רכ"ו that on Shabbat the Seder is held during the day since the Jews aren't accustomed to leave their homes on Friday night. This would imply that otherwise the Seder would take place during the day.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's [this](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/3711) Rabbi Adir HaKohen who brings a small *siman* (from *Rosh HaShanah daf 14b*) for why the focus is the evening.

In addition, [here's](http://www.93fm.co.il/radio/48836/) a collection of *halachos* for *Tu BiShvat*, where the rabbi brings one source for day (*Even Yisrael*) and two for night (*Yafe LaLev* and *Moed Lekol Chai*). Do not know these sources well enough, sorry :)

Comment: I would add that the Even Yisrael (here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26905&st=&pgnum=30) quotes at least 10 sources as to the concept of the Tu B'Shvat Seder and its' appropriate time. Excellent research!