# PTIJ: Why are we required to have so many Seders?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

On Passover, we are required to eat a substantial amount of ritually designated food, and also a proper holiday level meal. This is the obligation of a "seder". Two nights of this (in the diaspora) is fine. Throw in a Tu b'Shvat [seder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13200/tu-bshvat-seder) and I can still fit in my pants.

But I found that in Israel, and even outside, many yeshivot have a night seder MOST EVERY NIGHT! And add to that there are [books](https://www.eichlers.com/seder-hayom-nenukad.html) about, lectures about and the Israeli [government](https://main.knesset.gov.il/Activity/committees/Pages/AllCommitteesAgenda.aspx?Tab=3&ItemID=2150429) and [others](https://lcm.touro.edu/beis-medrash-ltalmud/seder-hayom/) even have codified what one needs for a "Seder [Hayom](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/903777/rabbi-yehoshua-rubenstein/having-a-seder-hayom-from-beginning-to-end-what-this-really-means-introduction-to-seder-hayom-series-/)" -- EVERY DAY!

Ignoring the amount of time required to prepare and hold a proper seder, and the monetary investment, I am wondering about the calorie intake demanded. Have any commentators explained why it is essential that we have so many ritual meals throughout the year?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 12):

[Deuteronomy 16:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.16.3?lang=bi):

> לְמַ֣עַן תִּזְכֹּר֔ אֶת־י֤וֹם צֵֽאתְךָ֙ מֵאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם כֹּ֖ל יְמֵ֥י חַיֶּֽיךָ׃‏
>
> So that you may remember the day of your departure from the land of Egypt every day of your lives.

There is a commandment to remember the Exodus from Egypt each and every day. Obviously, the way we do that is by holding a Seder at least once a day. (And according to [Ben Zoma](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berakhot.1.5?lang=bi) every night as well.)

Answer (score 6):

Most of those aren't food-based Seders, but precisely the opposite - the kind described in the Mishnah (Taanis 2:1) as סדר תעניות, "the seder of fasts." To take your example of night seder, for instance, most yeshivos won't allow the bochurim to eat during them.